# Conversion of code from Oracle 8i to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

How to convert the code below from Oracle 8i to MySQL-

```
select count(*) 

from   patient_visit,
        organization_master
where patient_visit.organization_id=organization_master.organization_id(+);
```

In the where statement "organization_master.organization_id(+)" is not working in MySQL.

Pls suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The (+) is an Oracle-specific notation for an outer join.
I think you should write something like this

```
select count(*)     
FROM patient_visit
LEFT OUTER JOIN organization_master
ON patient_visit.organization_id=organization_master.organization_id
```

I haven't tested it since I have no data to test it but it should work.

Hope it helps

Comment: Will OUTER JOIN work in following case where more than 2 tables and more than 2 statements in where clause as below-                                                                          select count(*) 
from  
 patient_visit ,
patient_registration ,
organization_master 
where 
patient_visit.ghm_hosp_id   = i_hosp_id
and    patient_registration.pprn_regd_id    = patient_visit.pprn_regd_id;
and    patient_visit.com_organization_id = organization_master.com_organization_id(+);

Comment: OUTER JOIN will work for multiple joins too. Before calling every table you need to add the JOIN statement. You should use an (inner) JOIN when you are not using the (+) and an OUTER JOIN when using (+).
            

select count(*)
from patient_visit
JOIN patient_registration
ON patient_visit.pprn_regd_id = patient_registration.pprn_regd_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN organization_master
ON patient_visit.com_organization_id = organization_master.com_organization_id;       

didn't use the clause "where patient_visit.ghm_hosp_id = i_hosp_id" since don't know which table has i_hosp_id

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the standard `JOIN` syntax which is supported by all modern SQL databases (also Oracle):

```
select    count(*)
from      patient_visit
left join organization_master
       on patient_visit.organization_id = organization_master.organization_id
```

If you have other joins without the `(+)`, then just replace those with `inner join`: avoid the comma completely in the `from` clause. Other, non-join conditions just stay in the `where` clause.

For example:

```
select     count(*)
from       patient_visit
inner join patient_registration 
        on patient_registration.pprn_regd_id = patient_visit.pprn_regd_id
left join  organization_master 
        on patient_visit.com_organization_id = organization_master.com_organization_id
where      patient_visit.ghm_hosp_id = i_hosp_id
```

Comment: Thanks. But if the select statement is having one more table and two more equate statements like below-Whether LEFT OUTER JOIN will work here

Comment: select count(*) 
from  
 patient_visit ,
patient_registration ,
organization_master 
where 
patient_visit.ghm_hosp_id   = i_hosp_id
and    patient_registration.pprn_regd_id    = patient_visit.pprn_regd_id;
and    patient_visit.com_organization_id = organization_master.com_organization_id(+);

Comment: Sure that will work. Just use `inner join` for where you don't have the `(+)`. Look around on this site, there are tons of examples to find. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I will try with that.